# Is there a definite way to respawn a boss?

Tags: genshin-impact

Sometimes, when farming materials, I'll want to challenge the same boss again and again.

Thing is, sometimes I lose time because I teleport away and back and the boss has not respawned yet.

So what are the requirements to respawn a boss? is there something to do that will always respawn the boss?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normal bosses like [Anemo Hypostasis](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Anemo_Hypostasis) or [Cryo Regisvine](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Cryo_Regisvine) have a respawn time of about 3 minutes. Note that the time only counts down when you left the current area. I cannot find exact data but people writing in comments [here in the wiki](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Bosses).

It's also stated that there's a timer in your adventure handbook once you killed a boss which tells the remaining time until respawn.

Weekly bosses can be challenged without a respawn timer as they're in a domain(except the Wolf of the North Challenge), but you can only claim the reward once per week. The week resets at Monday, 4AM server time.

Answer (score 4):

Anecdotally, bosses that don't spawn immediately, such as the Golden Wolflord, can be force respawned after claiming rewards by quitting the game and logging back in.

As Chriz mentions, some other bosses have a respawn timer of a few minutes.